# React storing multiple values in one useState variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Hello I would like to ask, if so good/proper way to store multiple data in one object in `useState` like this  and if so what im doing wrong.

I would like to automatically fetch data from api and show them on screen my problem is that the data gets fetched and they are stored in `x` in array but when I try run

```
setUser(x[0].first_name,x[0].last_name,x[0].tel_number,x[0].department)
```

then the only thing I can find when i try `console.log(user)`

is the `first_name` data and nothing else

I though it would store data like this and then I could show them with `{user.first_name}` ..etc

```
function ShowUser () {


const url = 'http://localhost:3001/showUser'
const [user, setUser] = useState({
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    tel_number: "",
    dep: ""
});

async function fetchData(){
    let response = await fetch(url)
    const x = await response.json();

    setUser(x[0].first_name,x[0].last_name,x[0].tel_number,x[0].department) 
}

useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;


    fetchData();
     return () => {
        console.log("cancelled!")
        controller.abort();   
    }; 
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setUser(x[0].first_name,x[0].last_name,x[0].tel_number,x[0].department)
```

`setUser` takes only one parameter. All the rest are ignored. If you want to store an object in state you can, but you'll need to create that object and pass it as the first (and only) argument:

```
setUser({
  first_name: x[0].first_name,
  last_name: x[0].last_name,
  tel_number: x[0].tel_number,
  dep: x[0].department,
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! working smoothly!:) may I have one more question. this is only for storing data for one user .. consider that there are multiple users and I would like to create some for cycle to fetch those data for users one by one and displaying them. I thought something like using this user and after every fetch and every useState to store this object into array and after its done and the display part comes it would go thru this array and display stored data, is it good way to do this or should I use something else?